# LINQ Selecting particular element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Basically, I am having trouble trying to understand where I am going wrong in here..

Basically, I have the following XML:

```
<Directory>
  <CustDirectory name="Name1">
  <Person name="Foo" />
  <Person name="Goo" />
  <Person name="Gentu" />
  </CustDirectory>

  <CustDirectory name="Name2">
  <Person name="F22" />
  <Person name="Gentu" />
  </CustDirectory>
</Directory>
```

Using forms, I am updating a list of contacts and I want to write the list to XML depending on which category (stored as a string).

What I have decided to use is therefore LINQ to do it, but, I can't seem to figure out there `.Where` and have read through questions on stackoverflow and can't seem to figure it out.

Here is my attempt:

```
var con = e.Element("Directory").Element("CustDirectory").Descendants("Person").Where(p => p.Attribute("name").Value.ToStr == "Name2");
```

This does not work and throws up a null exception... When I take off the `.Where` clause, the data contained in the descendent shows correctly.

Could anyone please tell me where I am going wrong in terms of the LINQ query so I can select all the descendants of a particular root?

Comment: what is `e` referring to?

Comment: What is `ToStr` ? `XAttribute.Value` is already a string.

Comment: @Selman22 Sorry, `e` is referring to the `XElement e` with the parsed in XML

Comment: If this is the XML and the code it should return 0 elements, because you are looking for a nonexistent name. If you replace the "Name2" with "Foo" for instance it will work.

Comment: Is the attribute with value Name2 not on the element CustDirectory? You seem to be searching the person sub elements..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question you are trying to extract all the Person elements that belongs to a given CustDirectory. In this case you should use something more like:

```
var con = e.Element("Directory").Descendants("CustDirectory").Where(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == "Name2").Elements("Person");
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks right except for the `ToStr` part.

To select only the `Person` elements under the `CustDirectory` with the name `Name2` you will need to put your `Where` on that, like this:

```
var con = e.Element("Directory").Elements("CustDirectory")
    .First(cd => cd.Attribute("name").Value == "Name2").Descendants("Person");
```

Note that I changed `Element("CustDirectory")` to `Elements("CustDirectory")`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Element("Directory")` at the beginning, because `e` it self is already referenced `<Directory>` (different case if `e` is an `XDocument` instead of `XElement` as you said in comment). This example able to return `<Person>` nodes give sample XML posted in question :

```
var e = XElement.Parse("...");
var con = e.Elements("CustDirectory")
           .Where(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == "Name2")
           .Elements("Person");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void Main()
{
    var xml  = @"<Directory>
    <CustDirectory name=""Name1"">
    <Person name=""Foo""/>
    <Person name=""Goo""/>
    <Person name=""Gentu""/>
    </CustDirectory>
    <CustDirectory name=""Name2"">
    <Person name=""F22""/>
    <Person name=""Gentu""/>
    </CustDirectory>
    </Directory>";
    var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var con = xmlDoc.Element("Directory")
                    .Elements("CustDirectory")
                    .Where(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == "Name2")
                    .Descendants("Person")
//  added bonus to get a specific node

                    .Where(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == "F22");
    Console.WriteLine(con);


}
```